# Rails 3.2 - How can I implement multi-tenant themes with Bootstrap?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, multi-tenant

I'm implementing a site that has accounts tied to one of 10-20 brands.  Each `user` `belongs_to` an `account`.  Each `account` `has_many` `users` and `has_one` `brand`.  There will be a common login URL across all brands, and the user will see their account's brand after authentication.  (I will will not be implementing sub-domains.)

I want to leverage the industry knowledge and quasi standardization around Bootstrap, but I don't see that there is a "standard" way to implement mult-brand Bootstrap on a site in general, and a Rails implementation specifically.  I'm assuming that the best approach would be to have a `"brand_" + brand_id.tos + "_config.scss"`construct identify the config file (or LESS equivalent, depending on which Rails Bootstrap plug-in is used) that sets the CSS brand attributes.

I'm a asset pipeline novice, so I'm not sure how the this approach would impact the pipeline and I'm not sure what would be the correct way to insert the brand configuration file into the pipeline.  Any suggestions on how to implement this approach?  Any resources on the web/SO that I've missed?